# Mass Spell Recursion & Storm

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If one overloads a card such as [Mizzix's Mastery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMizzix%27s%5d%2b%5bMastery%5d) to recur a graveyard full of instant/Sorceries, including a card with Storm ([Grapeshot](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrapeshot%5d)). Will Storm trigger for each spell you're also casting from the graveyard? As I understand storm is an on-cast trigger, so does order stacking matter in this instant?

This is question is not specific to Mizzix's Mastery or Grapeshot. If there is a better example of Mass Recursion & Storm please use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The spells cast by Mizzix's Mastery would count towards the storm count if you casted them in the correct order.**

---

From the Gather rulings under Mizzix's Mastery:

> If Mizzix’s Mastery exiled multiple cards, you may cast the copies in any order. The last copy you cast will be the first one to resolve.

The correct play to maximize your storm count would be to cast every spell other than Grapeshot first, and then cast Grapeshot last.

For instance, lets say your graveyard had [Time Walk](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=time%20walk), [Ancestral Recall](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382841), and Grapeshot, and you had casted no other spells that turn.

1. You cast overloaded Mizzix's Mastery (Storm=1)
2. Each player passes priority, Mizzix's Mastery resolves.
3. Exile Time Walk, Ancestral Recall, and Grapeshot, making copies of each of them
4. Cast the copy of Time Walk (Storm=2)
5. Cast the copy of Ancestral Recall (Storm=3)
6. Cast the copy of Grapeshot
7. Grapeshot's Storm ability triggers on cast with the Storm count equal to 3
8. Place 3 copies of Grapeshot on the stack on top of the original Grapeshot
9. Each player passes priority, Grapeshot storm copy 3 resolves
10. Each player passes priority, Grapeshot storm copy 2 resolves
11. Each player passes priority, Grapeshot storm copy 1 resolves
12. Each player passes priority, Grapeshot Mizzix copy resolves
13. Each player passes priority, Ancestral Recall copy resolves
14. Each player passes priority, Time Walk copy resolves

Comment: Just so we're clear: it's the spells CAST before Grapeshot that count as increasing the storm, NOT the spells RESOLVED before Grapeshot, right?

Comment: @Nzall correct, I'll update the answer to add that in there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the order matters, but luckily you can cast [Grapeshot](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426588) last, so that you can have maximum number of storm copies.

Comment: Beat me by 47 seconds!

Comment: Yes I did, but your answer is better!